# python installation of pandas-datareader fails with Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: )

Tags: python, cython

On windows 7 (Home Edition) x86 64 bit machine, I have installed python

```
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/python-3.7.0b4-amd64.exe
```

Then in Windows command prompt (`cmd`) typed

```
python -m pip install pandas-datareader
```

This downloads some stuff but fails with the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Cython
```

If I check using `python -m pip list` it does not show pandas-datarerader

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Python version 3.6 as 3.7 is not supported by `pandas-datareader`.

You can see the supported version of Python from the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-datareader/) for the package.

I recommend uninstalling 3.7 completely, rebooting your machine, and then installing the latest 3.6 version for Windows.